# VSTO - visual studio code structuring

Tags: vba

I'm new to .NET from an extensive VBA background. I'm building an Excel add-in and have been struggling to find any guidance on line about control of code structure and layout in visual studio.

Comparing to the VBA environment, what I want to do is have different modules for the different components (e.g. one module with all the calculation subs, one module with all the formatting subs, one module with all the custom charting subs, etc.) but cannot find any guidance on how to set this up.

I've put the skeleton of the ribbon tab in, with some icons etc. and VS has automatically created tabs as follows:

- Ribbon1.Designer.vb, which appears to house setup code - adding groups and buttons etc.
- Ribbon1.vb, which now contains a few subs I've written in 'Public Class Ribbon 1'. This is the bit I want to "modularise".

I have tried creating another public class which didn't work, and a few other things. I also saw mention of "sub classes" though could not find any instructions/examples and couldn't get this going myself (or if I need to specify inheritance from one to another?).

From a user friendliness perspective for me, one tab in VS per category of subs would be the ideal but I'm amateur so definitely open to learning how to structure it all properly. Yes, I wish I had software engineering training!

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you maybe take a screenshot? For me it's not really whenever you're struggling with structuring your code, setting up your environment and what environment you're actually using. Depending on the focus this might also be better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: What you probably want are either separate or subordinate Namespaces. Everything in VBA is in the same namespace, which turns out to be aggravatingly messy, especially once you learn how to use a structured namespace environment.  Here's a starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/namespaces

Comment: Hi Seth and RBarryYoung - thank you both for the responses.
Barry, I read that page and it appears to be a lot more complex than I believe my problem to be so I may have misled by using the term 'structuring'.
In the image I added, basically I'm trying to achieve in Visual Studio, what I've shown in VBA:
- In VBA I have modules to help me keep different "topics" of code separate
- In VS, I seem to have to stick it all within 'Public Class Ribbon1'
So the question is, how can I separate the code into modules in Visual Studio?